# Two solutions to ODE converge to single solution at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $y_0$ is a solution to $y''+y'-2y=F(x)$ defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$; and that there is another solution, $y_1$ also defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $|y_1(x)-y_0(x)|\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

Here's what I've tried:

$$|y_1-y_0|=\frac{1}{2}\left|y_0''+y_0'-y_1''-y_1'\right|\le \frac12\left(\left|y_0''-y_1''\right| + \left|y_0'-y_1'\right|\right)$$

Now why should $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left|y_0''-y_1''\right|=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \left|y_0'-y_1'\right|=0$? I'd appreciate some hint(s).

Comment: You need more friction (i.e. a bigger coefficient on $y'$), or to assume that both solutions are bounded at infinity. As it is, the homogeneous equation has exponentially growing solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true: take $F$ constantly equal to zero; then both $0$ and $e^x$ are solutions, and their difference does not tend to zero as $x \to \infty$.